# Cannot send cross domain ajax request with post method

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, spring-mvc, cross-domain

I wrote rest service with `spring mvc`:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", headers="Accept=*/*", method = RequestMethod.POST,
        produces="application/json")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
@ResponseBody
public UserLoginedVO findUsByPass(HttpServletResponse response, 
        @RequestBody UserLoginCO userco) throws Exception{

    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*");

    UserLoginedVO usVO = userService.findUsByPass(userco.getUsername(), userco.getPassword());
    return usVO;
}
```

test with postman, it returns right result
I call this service by jquery like below:

```
var json = {"username":"giau", "password":"1234"};

$.ajax({
            data: JSON.stringify(json),
            url: 'http://192.168.1.119:8080/mos/api/users/login',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType:"application/json", 
            crossDomain:true,
            async:false,
            success:function(data)
            {
               alert("Data from Server"+JSON.stringify(data));
            },
            error:function(jqXHR,textStatus,errorThrown)
            {
               alert("You can not send Cross Domain AJAX requests: "+errorThrown);
            }
        }).done(function(data){
            alert("aaaaaa");
        });
```

I get an error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load.
>    No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.
>
> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS.

This disallows post json data to rest service with cross domain, although I use `crossDomail:true`

How can I fix this?

Comment: What do you mean? I needn't set  Access-Control-Allow-Origin in restful method??

Comment: `dataType: 'jsonp',` isn't this should be instead?

Comment: I also try jsonp, but cannot load service. I read some sources, they say that jsonp does not supports for GET method